# Access subclass from an ArrayList of superclass in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I know there are other questions like this but I found them quite hard to understand, so basically I have to make an ArrayList of a superclass, and then access its subclasses. I don't have a choice with this format as its specified in the assignment instructions.

So at the moment I have something that looks like this:

Student is a superclass, UndergraduateStudent is a subclass of Student, and unit is only found in UndergraduateStudent.

```
ArrayList<Student> std_list = new ArrayList<Student>();
UndergraduateStudent Bill = new UndergraduateStudent();
std_list.add(Bill);
((UndergraduateStudent) std_list.get(0)).unit.getAss1();
```

So basically i use type casting to access the subclass methods, but it makes for very complicated looking code, and i was wondering is their a neater way of doing this or a more simpler way?

Comment: The best solution: only call parent methods on the ArrayList items. Option 2: use instanceof and casting, almost as you're doing (without first checking type with instanceof, the cast is dangerous to do). Option 3: use the [Visitor Design Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) to emulate double-dispatch. This would be clean, would work, but may be more than you need at this stage.

Comment: Dangerous like, could potentially cause unforeseen errors or dangerous like i could probably just leave it and hope for the best?

Comment: If you cast before checking that the guessed sub-type is the correct type (using instanceof), your program will likely throw a class cast exception and will go belly-up. Dangerous as dangerous gets.

Comment: right fair enough